# How much data is read when autoRead is false?

Tags: java, netty

The Javadoc for `read()` says:

> Request to Read data from the Channel into the first inbound buffer,
>   triggers an ChannelInboundHandler#channelRead event if data was read,
>   and triggers a ChannelInboundHandler#channelReadComplete event so the
>   handler can decide to continue reading.

When `channel.config().setAutoRead(false)` and `read()` is called manually, how much is actually read? Assuming a TCP connection without codecs, will it read until the inbound buffer fills up, fire `ChannelInboundHandler#channelRead`, and then stop reading?

Looking at the [proxy example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyBackendHandler.java#L40-L51) it calls read() once per channelRead which seems to imply a one-to-one between a `read()` and channelRead event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The socketChannel has a class added called 
[AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator.html) which has default values as

```
static final int DEFAULT_MINIMUM = 64;
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL = 1024;
static final int DEFAULT_MAXIMUM = 65536;
```

So at first `1024 bytes` will be read and then it can increase or decrease depending on the consequent reads. You can tune it by adding

`socketChannel.config().setRecvByteBufAllocator(RecvByteBufAllocator allocator)`